# Android action listener to call a method in another class

Tags: android, button, action, listener

I have a listview with a button in each row. I have made a custom Adapter class and a ItemModel class to hold the data for each row. Inside the ItemModel class I have defined an ActionListener for the button. How can I call a method in another class from inside my button's action listener?

Right now if i say Classname clsName = new Classname();  and inside the actionlistener do clsName.methodName(variableToPass); <--- this all compiles but crashes when I click the button..Anyone know how to get this to work?

MyListModel Class

```
public class MyListItemModel{ //that's our book
private String title; // the book's title
private String description; //the book's description
int id; //book owner id
String key; //book key
private Context context;
Shelf shelf = new Shelf();  //shelf class


public MyListItemModel(Context c){
    this.context=c;

 }


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key){
    this.key = key;
}


OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener(){ // the book's action
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //code for the button action
        //THIS DOESN'T WORK PROPERLY AND CRASHES ON CLICK. However if i use a Toast to print the key on each click - it will print the right key to screen.

        shelf.downloadBook(new String(key));

    }
};
int getBookId(){

    return title.hashCode();
}
}
```

MyListAdapter class - method for getView

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

View renderer;
List<MyListItemModel> items;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;


public MyListAdapter(Context c){
    this.context=c;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

....

 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null){
        //convertView = renderer;
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.shelfrow, null);

    }
    MyListItemModel item = items.get(position);
    TextView label = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    label.setText(item.getTitle());
    TextView label2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_subtitle);
    label2.setText(item.getDescription());
    Button button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_download);
    button.setOnClickListener(item.listener);


    return convertView;
}
```

My Shelf class has a method called downloadBook(String bookKey) <-- this is what I want to call with each button click and pass this method the appropriate book key. I also have 2 xml files (shelfrow.xml and shelflist.xml). One contains the textfields and button and the other contains the listview.

Some of the code from Shelf.java class

```
List<MyListItemModel> myListModel = new ArrayList<MyListItemModel>();

            try{

                JSONArray entries = json.getJSONArray("entries");

                for(int i=0;i<entries.length();i++){                        

                    MyListItemModel item = new MyListItemModel(this);
                    JSONObject e = entries.getJSONObject(i);
                    item.id = i;        //user ID
                    bookKey = (e.getString("key"));
                    item.setTitle(e.getString("title"));
                    item.setDescription(e.getString("description"));

                                    myListModel.add(item);  
                        }

                    }catch(JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                    }


                    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this);
                    adapter.setModel(myListModel);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                    lv = getListView();
                    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 

….

 public void downloadBook(String theKey) {
      //take theKey and append it to a url address to d/l
  }
```

Stacktrace from logcat

```
05-23 02:34:59.439: INFO/wpa_supplicant(14819): Reset vh_switch_counter due to receive LINKSPEED cmd 05-23 02:34:59.439: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(1346): getMobileDataEnabled returning true 05-23 02:36:39.269: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(6068): onSignalStrengthsChange
```

also this came up zygoteinit methodandargscaller.run

Comment: Can you post the code within the listener class, and the exception you are getting?

Comment: ive updated my post with code. hope it is clear enough. thanks

Comment: I have some ideas, but it would be easier if we could also see the exception that is being thrown.

Comment: I think it is ...Shelf(ContextWraper).getResources() and InvocationTargetException

Comment: It has something to do with what I have in my ActionListener. I don't think its calling the downloadBook method correctly in the shelf class

Comment: That is not the stacktrace of the exception.  It is some random lines from the logcat output.  Your logcat output should be putting out the exception once the application fails.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a limb here, but I think I know what the issue is.

In the last snippet of code, you are not setting the `key` field on the `MyListItemModel`.  You are instead setting some variable called 'bookKey' (I do not see where it is defined).

I bet if you change this line:

```
bookKey = (e.getString("key"));
```

to be this:

```
item.setKey(e.getString("key"));
//or item.key = e.getString("key"));
```

everything will work just fine for you.  If you pass in a `null` String to the String(String) constructor, you will get a NullPointerException, as that constructor expects a non-null String.

I will mention that it is not necessary for you use the String(String) constructor, you should be fine just doing this in the fist snippet:

```
shelf.downloadBook(key);
```

Comment: it didnt' work. bookKey isnt really doing anything. It is a string variable in shelf that I used for something earlier. The book key was being set anyway by item.key = e.getString("key");    I am pretty sure that it is to do with creating a new object of the shelf class and trying to call its downloadBook method incorrectly.

Comment: As I said if i put this into the action listener then it will print the correct keys for each row, when you click the buttons.. -----Toast msg = Toast.makeText(context, "key = " + key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      msg.show();

Comment: Ok, well, I don't see where the key is being set, but I believe you.  Can you please post the stacktrace of the exception.  That will help the most.  Do not just write what it says, copy/paste it please.  You should be able to add it to the original post.

Comment: How to I find the stacktrace when I run in debug in Eclipse?

Comment: If you are running on the emulator, you should be able to find the stacktrace in the logcat output.

Comment: the logcat keeps changing in the debugger.. is there a file it writes to?

Comment: We do not need all of it, but the part that shows the stacktrace, which will happen when the exception occurs.

Comment: the main problem that I cannot get my head around is inside an Action Listener you cannot access any of your variables that exist outside of the block - only ones that you declare at the top of your code (in the class) and this is not good enough for dynamic coding

Comment: 05-23 02:34:59.439: INFO/wpa_supplicant(14819): Reset vh_switch_counter due to receive LINKSPEED cmd
05-23 02:34:59.439: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(1346): getMobileDataEnabled returning true      05-23 02:36:39.269: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(6068): onSignalStrengthsChanged

Comment: The stacktrace is what we need.  Also, you CAN access variables inside you ActionListener from outside of it.  You need to declare said variables as final to do it.  Your IDE of choice should be telling you this.

Comment: Please edit your question to also contain the stacktrace.  It will do us no good in the comments.

Comment: updated the post with the logcat although i'm not convinced it is of use

Comment: also i cannot use the Final keyword for these variables because they are dynamic and change - meaning that they will store Title's for many different books per row

Comment: This is definitely the code that makes it crash from the Adapter class...Shelf shelf = new Shelf(); and then....shelf.downloadBook(item.key);

Comment: SOLVED it! I decided to override the actionlistener in my shelf class so i did not need to create a new instance. I just changed the MyListItemModel item = new MyListItemModel(this); to final so that I could access it in the actionlistener. Thanks for the help because you made me think of that :)

Comment: also look at the very first code snipper that i posted (MyListModel Class) it has the Shelf shelf = new Shelf() and shelf.downloadBook.... but that doesn't matter anymore